# Using autocomplete combobox with extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4

My case is, I have an edit form, that gets its data from  a selected row of a grid.
In this form there is some fields of type "combobox", that I'm using autocomplete properties:

```
    xtype: 'combobox',
    store: 'Paciente',
    forceSelection: true,
    typeAhead: true,
    pageSize: 10,
    fieldLabel: 'Paciente',
    name: 'paciente_id',
    valueField: 'id',
    displayField: 'nome',
    allowBlank: false,
    afterLabelTextTpl: required
```

this is my store:

```
Ext.define('App.store.Paciente', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
  model: 'App.model.Paciente',
  pageSize: 10,
  proxy: {
      type: 'rest',
      format: 'json',
      url: 'pacientes',
      reader: {
          root: 'pacientes',
          totalProperty: 'totalCount'
      }
  }
});
```

The combo works, when using it. But when I select a line in the grid, all fields get filled, but not the combos.

```
gridSelectionChange: function(model, records) {
    if (records[0]) {
        this.getForm().load(records[0]);
    }
},
```

How can I get this combo filled correctly when the form is loaded?

**Update 1: working code**

I had to do this manually for each combobox. I thought that was an automatically way..

```
if (records[0]) {
        this.getForm().loadRecord(records[0]);

        //updating current value for combo paciente 
        this.getStore('Paciente').add({nome: records[0].get('nome'), id: records[0].get('id')});
        this.getCombopaciente().select(records[0].get('paciente_id'));

        //updating current value for combo XYZ...
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default combo loads store only when expanding. In your case it has no data to display.
You can call store **load** method manualy or set autoload property in combo config.

Comment: But what this autoload will load ? The entire table? I really need that it loads only the record with its id. There are some tables with thousands of records, like this Pacients.

Comment: You've defined reader for a store. As i see, it reads data from 'pacientes' url. Is not it? If you want to add manualy, see store add method http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-add

Comment: Hi Prodigy, please see my Update 1. Thanks.

Comment: I can tell you only that you can compose array from you comboboxes, and make walk on array. Something like:   `combo.store.add({combo.displayField: records[0].get(combo.displayField), id: records[0].get('id')});`